# Dose mysql support hypothetical index(or what-if index) like PostgreSQL and SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing

When it comes to some problems like index advisor or query plan choice, hypothetical index feature is so important and many AI4DB papers use PG because of it. However, I can't find any similar feature in Mysql. So I wonder if Mysql supports such feature, if not, how hard is it to develop one like hypopg?

I've tried to find some information about hypothetical index in Mysql but find nothing.

Comment: I'm not aware of mysql having hypothetical indexes. I don't think anyone can estimate how long it would take to develop such feature without doing some serious planning.

Comment: thank you@Shadow, has mysql official ever planned to develop such feature?

Comment: That's a question for Mysql AB, not for the community.

Comment: I'll do one better -- show me the `SELECT`, I'll tell you the optimal `INDEX`.  Note that a Hypothetical index only lets you discover that an index would be good, not that it would be the best.  (The best is often a composite index.)

Comment: thank you@Shadow. I think Hypothetical index is essential to recommending indexes because we need to judge wheather a index is good or not without actually create it.@Rick James